# ActiveForm Name in yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

i'm using `Yii2` and `ActiveForm`.
in normal if any input in `ActiveForm` has used, input's name should be same as `ActiveRecord` attribute which is name of a column of related table in Database.

for some reason i want to use Active `TextArea` and it's name is also different from Active Record attributes.Actually i want to get `TextArea's` value and explode then save to database.

is there a way to use a ActiveInput with different name from ActiveRecord attributes?

View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
             'id'=>'import-student',
             'options'=>[
                 'class'=>'form-horizontal',
                 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
             ]); ?>    

    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name', ['inputOptions'=>[
                             'placeholder'=>'import Users as text']])
             ->textArea(['rows'=>'12','class'=>'form-control'])
             ->label(false); ?>  
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submint', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?> 

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionImport()
{
    $model = new Student();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $users = $model->saveTextArea()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', print_r($users));
    } 

    return $this->render('import',[
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
}
```

Model:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('backend', 'ID'),
        'first_name' => Yii::t('backend', 'First Name'),
        'last_name' => Yii::t('backend', 'Last Name'),
        'user_id' => Yii::t('backend', 'User ID'),
        'student_number' => Yii::t('backend', 'Student Number'),
        'national_id' => Yii::t('backend', 'National ID'),
        'average' => Yii::t('backend', 'Average'),
        'vip' => Yii::t('backend', 'Vip'),
        'location_id' => Yii::t('backend', 'Location ID'),
    ];
}
public function SaveTextArea()
{
    $users = explode(";", $this->first_name);
    foreach ($users as $user){
        list($first_name,$last_name,$student_number,$national_id) = explode(";", $user);
    }
    return $ali;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the details of your code so that people can help you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just add a public attribute inside your model class:

```
class MyClass extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $myAttribute;
    ...
```

You also need to declare it as a safe attribute and it's type inside your rules method:

```
public function rules()
{
    ...
    [['myAttribute'], 'safe'],
    ...
```

and after that you can do any processing using another rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    ...
    [['myAttribute'], 'safe'],
    [['myAttribute'], 'myCustomFunction'],
    ...
}

public function myCustomFunction($attribute, $params)
{
    // Do explode and assign attribute values here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use

```
\yii\helpers\Html::textarea('the_name_you_need', 'value', options)
```

This way you will not be obliged to use an ActiveRecord attribute

You can read about it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#textarea()-detail).